# How does React prevent an <input> with a value property from changing?

Tags: html, reactjs

[Controlled forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) are a well-known React-ism. When the `value` property is added to an `<input>` tag, the tag no longer changes on its own, and must be controlled via `state` and an `onChange` event handler. React even gives you a friendly warning if you set `value` without setting an `onChange`.

However, this is not true in vanilla HTML - an `<input>` element with a value set is fully writable.

[The contrast in behavior can be seen in this codepen](https://codepen.io/adadev/pen/wRapLL?editors=1010). Notice that the component does not re-render when you type in the readonly box, implying that the value is *not* frozen because React re-renders with the old static value. React is somehow blocking the DOM's default behavior.

This leads to three questions:

1. Why (from a design standpoint) is React's behavior here different than the DOM on its own?
2. By what mechanism does this occur?
3. Does this different philosophy about how the DOM should behave appear anywhere else?

I assume the answer to 2 involves something about the shadow DOM and [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), but I haven't yet found a concise description of how this works or why it changes the behavior of an `<input>` specifically.

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMInput.js#L41-L56 for #2

Comment: @AndrewLi does this mean React does not use the HTML input directly to avoid it being writable by default?