# Why can we update a value of a number input using mouse wheel?

Tags: reactjs

Why is it possible to update the value of a `input[type="number"]` using the mouse wheel in React but not in pure HTML?

React: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-morse-l28c7 or https://jsfiddle.net/nm53bavd/

HTML: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-davinci-il8rn?file=/src/index.js

What's the secret? Couldn't find any hint in the react docs or related react issues on github.

I want to get rid of it globally, found some useful stuff like

```
onWheel={event => event.target.blur()}
```

But anyway, if this is not documented anywhere (please correct me if i am wrong) and it differs to the current default behavior of HTML should a bug ticket be opened to have this issue fixed in react itself?

Comment: Notice when talking about native HTML input, you might get different wheel behavior across browsers, it depends on browser's input implementation. So what you trying to do sounds like a bad practice overall

Comment: Yap, it depends on the browser. But as you can see in the examples i posted the input element behavior varies in the !same! browser depending on the usage of react. Getting rid of annoying (inconsistent) stuff cannot be a bad practice :)

Answer (score 1):

[React DOM elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) are cross-browser implementations of HTML elements.

> You can find the `input` implementation in [`ReactDOMInput.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMInput.js) file.

Therefore the "secret" is behind adding the wheel event implementation.

You can't "get rid of it" globally since you can't edit the DOM elements implementation out of the box.

So, you can write your own custom `InputNoWheelEvent` component with your desired change:

```
// InputNoWheelEvent
<input onWheel={event => event.target.blur()} {...inputProps}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and coming up with a work around solution. So react adds wheel event listening to number input fields for the sake of cross browser consistency? If that's the case i am the unlucky guy who would need it the other way around. Chrome, Firefox and Edge don't support it natively. Safari does 

Comment: After writing the last comment i am more motivated to create a github ticket for react because cross browser consistency handling should be implemented to fix a few outliers / minority, shouldn't it? Desktop Safari is used by 10% (https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/worldwide, more than i thought to be honest) but it's the only browser (minority from technical point of view). So why should the default behavior be changed for 90% of the users using all the other browsers?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing... I have created an issue, I don't know if you did it at the time you posted? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24986